# Run a shell command when a specific object is detected in YOLO

Tags: yolo

Hi I don't have much experience in C or YOLO so does anyone know what edits in demo.c I should make to be able to run a shell command whenever a specific object is detected?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have some experience with .NET/C#.

You need install this two nuget packages in your project after this you can copy my exampel code. If yolo detect a motorbike a external process are starting. If you need some other objects you can use your own yolo model instead of YoloV2TinyVocData.

```
Install-Package Alturos.Yolo
Install-Package Alturos.YoloV2TinyVocData
```

Example code

```
var configurationDetector = new ConfigurationDetector();
var config = configurationDetector.Detect();
using (var yoloWrapper = new YoloWrapper(config))
{
    var items = yoloWrapper.Detect(@"image.jpg");
    foreach(var item in items)
    {
        if (item.Type.Equals("Motorbike", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            Process.Start("yourcommand.exe");
        }
    }
}
```